# Excel Formula Help (value return) two different workbooks

Tags: excel, formula

whats the best formula to do the following:

```
workbook A
Region Market   Ring ID
San Fran        SF0001
San Diego       SD0001
San Fran        SF0002
San Fran        SF0005
```

So i have a new workbook "workbook B", and what i want to bring into workbook B is:

in workbook A - Column A, look at all that says "San Fran" and return the value from workbook A - Column B into column A of workbook B. so in my new workbook B i want to see:

```
workbook B
Ring ID
SF0001
SF0002
SF0005
```

Comment: spreadsheet B is a different workbook or a different sheet in the same workbook? Can you not simply use a pivottable or a filter ?

Comment: or you can use an advance filter.

Comment: Its a different workbook. the reference sheet constantly changes, im trying to build something where it automatically pulls all the sites for me based on the market